# Postgres DB Timezone Change

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-9.5, timezone

Can You please guide us on how we can change the time zone of the Database to UTC which is migrated from AWS which was in time zone UTC? Now the Postgres 12 is installed in Ubuntu 20 which shows (show timezone; Asia/Kolkata ). We also want to make sure all the existing data inside the database should be changed to the new timezone. Because It is creating issues for the operation team to query on DB as all other DB in the env are in UTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the parameter by editing `postgresql.conf` or with `ALTER SYSTEM` via SQL. Don't forget to reload the database.

But you should tell the application development team that they have messed up. If the application relies on a certain setting of `timezone`, then the application has to set that parameter itself. The parameter can be changed using the `SET` SQL statement.

If you don't care about time zone handling by PostgreSQL at all, you should use the data type `timestamp without time zone`.